# Circularity In Definition Of Force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, definition

So my college physics book defines a force as a push/pull, but mainly a vector quantity, having both magnitude (strength) and direction.

Yet it also defines the unit of a Newton, as THE FORCE, required to accelerate a 1 kg object 1 m/s^2

My questions is, isn't that kind of circular or misleading? How can we call a Newton a force, yet it not have a direction? Or does it not matter in that a newton is a unit, so it is understood to be that general force, regardless of direction. And when necessary or specific, obviously a force has direction.

Looking for input as to why a force is defined as having direction, but many times forces (like the example definition of a newton) are defined with not direction at all.

Comment: Think of the Newton as the unit for the magnitude of a force, not as a force itself which has magnitude and direction.

Comment: This was the same answer as Steeven. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of the Newton unit is refering to the force *magnitude* only. As you say yourself, direction is not included in the mentioned definition - but remember that force can be considered both with and without direction. It depends on the scope, the frame, it is used within. Just as how a force can be considered two- or three-dimensional or more depending on the space you are working within.

Also, note how the Newton unit is defined from force (as well as the units of mass, distance and time) whereas force is *not* defined from the Newton. There is no circular definition here. The mentioned definition of force *is* a tad vague, though, I'd give you that. This is more of an intuitive definition or description than a proper technical definition.

Technically, force is defined via Newton's 2nd law:

$$\sum F=ma.$$

Comment: "force is defined via Newton's 2nd Law" When operating within Newtonian physics, sure. Once you're dealing with relativity, that definition is no longer accurate.

Comment: @nick012000 Sure. Let's keep it within the scope of the question, though.

Comment: @steeven, in regards to my question, is there a reason why many times we ignore the direction when talking about force? It is just as you said, sometimes it depends on scope or we are just lazy ans it is understood? Thks

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz We ignore direction when direction is not relevant for our purpose. The police officer only cares about magnitude when measuring the speed of drivers on the motorway. Not direction. Whereas NASA cares a lot about direction apart from velocity magnitude of a near-coming comet.

Comment: @steeven, guess what confused me is how can we define force as having both direction and magnitude,  yet we define the newton as a force,....using the same word but not the same as it is doesn't have direction. Guess it's because as you say, it's being used generally to refer to the force magnitude and it's understood  without overthunking....correct?

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz Ahh, I see your point. The reason is, I believe, that the vector version of a property consists of scalars, so to say. Thus, defining the Newton as a scalar unit works for all cases. You could think of each coordinate in the vector as having a unit and then we simply "take that unit out of the vector-bracket" and then it works as a unit for the vector as well: $$\begin{pmatrix} 3\,\mathrm{N}\\4\,\mathrm{N} \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 3\\4 \end{pmatrix} \mathrm{N}.$$

Comment: @steeven, not sure I understand,  but are you saying since we can express and work with force as a vector and at times like a scalar, the unit is generic? It is essentially  defined as force so whether we break it down as specifically a vector quantity or scalar, it works in both cases. You are right, the vector has scalar components, and a newton is a force in a general sense, and when asked for the true vector qty, we just have to include the direction. Agree?

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz Yes, I agree with your two here if I understand them right. The Newton unit is essentially defined as a scalar unit. Not as a vector unit. Since vectors can be expressed from scalar quantities, as you point out, the Newton thus applies for vectors as well.

Comment: @steeven, thanks, and that makes sense too why a newton get called a "FORCE" , because at the end of the day, we need a unit to measure it either way. As you said originally,  force in the definition of a newton is more general, referring  to the magnitude/scalar force, but that is understood  regardless. Sorry I was reading into it. Thanks again

Answer (score 8):

The definition of the newton is not a definition of force in general. It is the definition of a unit in the SI system. There is nothing circular or misleading there. Even using your quoted definition, the definition of the newton depends on the definition of force, but the definition of force does not depend on the definition of the newton. So that is linear, not circular.

Note that the newton is not officially defined in terms of force anyway. The newton is defined simply as $1\text{ N}=1\text{ kg m s}^{-2}$ as seen in the official SI brochure:

https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf/2d2b50bf-f2b4-9661-f402-5f9d66e4b507?version=1.9&download=true

Any statement defining the newton otherwise is not the official definition but an individual conclusion or description.

Comment: many places define it as the force require.....https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_(unit) I am curious how they can call it a force if there is no direction given

Comment: Only the BIPM has the authority to define SI units

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz I've just fixed the Wiki definition you quoted.

Comment: @DanielC: It appears your change to the Wikipedia definition [was reverted](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MobileDiff/1044904989) as it doesn't match official definitions

Comment: @Eric. Of course, it got reverted, because "official definitions" are sloppy, and people love sloppy formulations of definitions.

Comment: Well, the reversion doesn’t match the official definition either. Wikipedia and its community don’t get to define the newton. Only the BIPM can define the newton

Comment: @dale, would you agree that a newton is a unit of magnitude of force? That the Newton itself is not the definition of force as you say so there's no circularity but is a unit of the forces magnitude / strength

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz the newton is just another word for kg m s^-2. So you can use “newton” any place that you could use “kg m s^-2”. You can use those units for the magnitude of force, for each component of force, and for force as a geometric vector quantity. It is not tied to the mathematical representation.

Comment: @dale, Okay so then in that defintion I stated originally, it shoudl say a newton is kgm/s2, which is a unit of magnitude  of force..agree? They were being lazy and general.

Comment: @ dale, can you confirm my comment above to confirm my understanding? Wikipedia and other definitions are more lazy and loose. They should be more explicit but probably  because many times it doesn't matter, definitions  become  generalized.

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz I disagree with your comment. As I said previously “You can use those units for the magnitude of force, for each component of force, and for force as a geometric vector quantity. It is not tied to the mathematical representation”. The newton is not tied to vectors, scalars, magnitudes, etc.

Comment: @dale, perhaps I don't understand,  but I thought I could use the unit newton  for measuring the magnitude of force? What's wrong with that? Only thing that's different  than what you say is its not specific to just that, is that what you mean? Newton is a unit of force, for magnitude, component of force, etc...all of the above. Corrct?

Comment: @DALE, also don't you agree that Wikipedia is a lazy general defintion. I feel they left it generic for a broader audience

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz have you looked at the Wikipedia definition recently? It is accurate now. You can use the newton for measuring magnitude, component, or vector force. So the word “magnitude” should **not** be part of the definition.

Comment: @dale, the Wikipedia page reverted.  Plus reasosn I state newton is a unit of measure for force, but it's of magnitude only, as there is no direction.  If a force is a vector, again how can you define a newton's as a force or the force required to accelerate a 1kg mass. It makes sense if a netwon is a unit of force, but magnitude only  no direction

Comment: @dale, when I look at definition of a newton, they always call it a force. Force shoukd have direction, but a newton doesn't its just a unit. So that why it's confusing. How can that call it "the force required to accelerate etcetc." But there is no direction with a unit newton. https://www.britannica.com/science/newton-unit-of-measurement

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz I just checked it a moment ago. The Wikipedia definition is currently correct. I disagree completely with your fixation on the magnitude. I don’t know how I can be more clear about that.

Comment: @dale, How can a newton be "a force", if no direction is given. Right from Wikipedia it says " A newton is defined as 1 kg⋅m/s2, which is the force which gives a mass of 1 kilogram an acceleration of 1 metre per second, per second". Doesn't a force require magnitude AND direction. So for the unit of a newton, please tell me the direction? I thunk your missing my point no direction is given so to call it a force is very vague. YES WE

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz why do you think that a unit for a vector quantity must also be a vector? There is no such requirement. A newton is not a force, it is a unit of force. A force is a vector, a unit of force is not

Comment: @dale, because the unit is in my examples being defined as  a force, which is a vector. But I agree, the unit clearly isn't a vector. So that leads my back to my original  question. Are they using the term "force" generically in these example definitions but not necessarily  meaning a vector force?

Comment: @DALE, then based on your defintion  above, a newton is a unit  of force, but it pertains to the "amount  or strength or magnitude" of force.

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz this is getting exceptionally tiresome. You are simply repeating your points that I have already explicitly disagreed with above. I am done here. As I already said above “You can use the newton for measuring magnitude, component, or vector force. So the word ‘magnitude’ should not be part of the definition”. For your next repetition of what you have already said please simply see above for my response that I have already given. Goodbye

Comment: @dale, sorry Dale for arguing. Took me awhile to see but now i understand your point, units are units. They are historically arbitrary  and/ or calculated defined standard units that we use for measurement, and as such they can be used to measure scalar, vectors, magnitudes etc. To call them one or the other is not correct. I didn't see it right away but now I do. Thank you